# GET request with authorization header (with httparty or faraday)

Tags: ruby, httparty, faraday

I'm tring to use twitter api to fetch some data (Since https://github.com/sferik/twitter is not updaded anymore, some field that I need is left out)

I can get Postman working with fields that I defined, i.e., authorization with Oauth 1.0, consumer key and consumer secret.

[image]

My question: how to define these params in Ruby? using HTTParty or Faraday is fine.

I can only get something like this

```
  url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=balajis&exclude_replies=true&include_rts=false&count=100&tweet_mode=extended&trim_user=true'
  xml = HTTParty.get(url,
                     headers: {"Authorization" => "???"}).body
```

and after searching around I only find example using oauth 2.0 (like in https://github.com/lostisland/faraday_middleware/wiki/Oauth)

---

UPDATE

The code from Postmand does not have anything with authorization. Did I miss anything?

[image]

Comment: Click the "Code" link in your screenshot (directly below the Save button). Then click `Ruby > NET::Http`. Then research how to convert a net/http call to HTTParty or Faraday.

Comment: @anothermh could you see my update? There is no authorization in the code generated. Did I miss anything?

Comment: What does "Preview Request" on the left side give you?

Answer (score 0):

In the generated code snippets window, click the setting icon and enable the first option (Include Temporary Header)